# Change collation of a computed column

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2014, I have a table which contains French or Spanish strings with accents such `José` or `voilà`.

I would like this table to be searchable and have similar results if client searches for `José` or `Jose` or `JÔse`, etc...

To search it in SQL, I wanted to store a version of the column without any accents using the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI` collation into a computed column.

I tried to apply a specific collation to a computed column but I didn't succeed to do it. Is it possible? How would you approach such a case?

Thank you

Sylvain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you tried, but this works for me:

```
drop table if exists #foo;
create table #foo (a varchar(50) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS);
alter table #foo add b as a collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI ;

insert into #foo (a) values ('José')

select *
from #foo
where a = 'Jose'

-- returns 0 rows

select *
from #foo
where b = 'Jose'

-- returns 1 row
```

Note - if you're going to do equality predicates against the column with the other collation, you can index it w/o having to persist it.

Comment: Thank you @ben-thul, I didn't tried this syntax. It works great.